# Rails help create has many and belongs to assoction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is my user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :posts
end
```

Here is my post model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
before_create :ejer
belongs_to :user
def ejer
    self.user.build
end
end
```

I am using devise and when I have signed in and trying to create a post i gets this error:

```
NoMethodError in PostsController#create

undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass
```

I have created a column user_id  in posts table.

Why do I get the error and how do I assoctie current user that is signed in with the post?

Comment: Have you migrated your database?

Comment: Yes I have migrated my database

Comment: can you show the controller's code?

Comment: Yes here it is http://pastie.org/1903610

Comment: @post = Post.new(params[:post]), ok, but is user_id inside params[:post]?

Comment: no it is not. I was considering to use a hidden field for user_id in the form to create the assocition. But then the user could change the user_id param and hack who is the author of the post

Answer (score 0):

`self.user` will be `nil` so you're trying to run the method build on nil which will raise an exception like you're getting.

To add a user to the post you can just assign it by setting the attribute:

```
def ejer
  self.user = User.new
end
```

You could also use the build_user method

```
def ejer
  build_user
end
```

Or set the user to an existing user:

```
def ejer
  self.user = User.first
end
```

Comment: I have used the build_user but no user_id gets submitted in the database. The user_id should be the current_user.id

Comment: oh right, then you'll want to assign the user to the current user. `self.user = current_user`

Comment: Then I get a nameerror: undefined local variable or method `current_user'

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your comments in response to Mario you don't actually want to build a new user - that would create a new record.

I recommend taking a look at the [sentient_user gem](https://github.com/bokmann/sentient_user). Once you've hooked it up correctly in the models and controllers your posts model can become:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  validates :user, :presence => true

  before_validate do
    self.user ||= User.current_user
  end
end
```

I changed the hook to be `before_validate` and added a validation to ensure that there is a user associated since in most cases it doesn't make sense to allow a post to be created without a user id.

(oh and I'm sure there are other solutions to getting a User.current_user or equivalent, sentient_user is just the one I personally use.)